# Postgresql query to retrive last inserted row for each id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have PostgreSQL Database table with data as follows. Some Random values for lat and long values used here.

| id | date | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014-02-01 | 10 | 20.12 |
| 1 | 2014-02-01 | 20 | 30 |
| 1 | 2014-02-01 | 12 | 14 |
| 2 | 2014-02-02 | 12 | 16 |
| 2 | 2014-02-02 | 18 | 22 |
| 3 | 2014-06-12 | 23 | 10 |
| 3 | 2014-06-12 | 15 | 12 |
| 3 | 2014-06-12 | 85 | 72 |

Date column has same date for each id( Like, id 1 has 2014-02-01 for all rows), how to retrieve last inserted long and lat (coordinates) for each id in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  That is, there is no ordering, no "last insert" *unless a column has that information.

Two typical methods of storing this information:

- An `identity` column (or equivalently a `serial` column).
- A `created` timestamp (which isn't perfect because there can be duplicates).

If you had such a column, then Postgres offers `distinct on`, which is a very convenient way to do this:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
order by id, <ordering col> desc;
```

You may want to recreate your data using an auto-generated `identity` column so you can capture the insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT COL1,MAX(COL2)
 FROM TABLEA 
 GROUP BY COL1
```

May be you need this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(id), lat, long
FROM tableName
ORDER BY id;
```

This query gives you the last inserted `lat and long` for each id.

Comment: Not quite true. Without another column to specify the order you cannot predict the order of rows with the same id. Not only can you not predict the order the order may be different from run to run.